# Operation of a Group on a set. ~ Serge Lang, Algebra

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

[image]

I understood pretty much everything besides the last statement here. What does the author mean when he says the image of s under the permutation $\pi_x$? I mean the permutation isn't a mapping right? How would it have an image for an element? Any kind explanation especially with an example will be very much appreciated.

Comment: $\pi_x$ is a permutation, so it *is* a mapping $\pi_x:S\rightarrow S$. In fact, it's a *bijective* mapping.

Comment: Naively, it means that each $x\in G$ induces a "shuffling" of the elements of $S$, as if $x$ was "moving" every element of $S$ to another one (with possibly no moving at all).

Comment: And the product $xx'$ induces the composition of "shufflings" $\pi_x\pi_{x'}$.

Comment: Please don't rely on pictures of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permutations are simply bijections from a set to itself, so $\pi_x$ *is* a mapping. Indeed, $\pi_x:S\rightarrow S$.

For example, let $G$ be a group with an index-$n$ subgroup $H$, and write $g_1H, \ldots, g_nH$ for the cosets. So we take $S=\{g_1H, \ldots, g_nH\}$. Take $x\in G$, and define $\pi_x$ by the rule $\pi_x(g_kH)=(xg_k)H=g_{k'}H\in S$ for some $g_{k'}$ (by results on cosets).

Defining each $\pi_x$ like this does define a homomorphism
\begin{align*}
\pi: G&\rightarrow \operatorname{Perm}(S)\\
x&\mapsto \pi_x
\end{align*}
and proving this is a nice exercise. But hopefully you see my point: $\pi_x$ is permutation of $S$, and so is clearly a map from $S\rightarrow S$.

The mapping $G\times S\rightarrow S$ here is simply $(x, g_kH)\mapsto (xg_kH)$.

Comment: Yep, this makes sense, I was think of Elements of Perm(S) as tuples rather than bijections, but yeah it all makes sense now, thanks!